# How do I assign the value of input to my url parameter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am adding a product to cart in WordPress using ajax link. I can add a product with no [extra product options](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619) using this code:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=11" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="11" data-product_sku="" class="add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
```

But the website that I am working on uses a plugin called [extra product options](https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619) that adds options like a checkbox or a date(booking purposes) before adding an item to cart

I can add a product to cart with the options included using the ajax link as long as I provide the **name** and **value** attribute **generated by the plugin** to the url. Take a look at the example below for a checkbox:

Html Checkbox Provided by the plugin:

```
<input class="tmcp-field" name="tmcp_checkbox_0_0" value="_0" type="checkbox">
```

I can add a product to cart with the name and value provided by extra product options and its checkbox **checked** if I create a link like this:

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=11&tmcp_checkbox_0_0=_0" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="11" data-product_sku="" class="add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Add to cart</a>
```

In my situation I am using a datepicker to set a booking date for a product. The html for the datepicker is: `<input type="text" class="tmcp-field" id="tmcp_date_1" value="" name="tmcp_date_0">`

The value of the datepicker html is always value="" even though I have selected a date for it unlike the checbox where there is already a value of checked or unchecked.

I am thinking of getting the value of the datepicker then pass it to a variable when a date is selected using jquery

```
$( "#epo-build-datepicker" ).datepicker({


    onSelect: function() {
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        console.log(dateObject);

        var paramValue = $(this).val();
        console.log("Date value is:" + paramValue);

    }

});
```

Do you know how can i pass the value of the selected date to my url param **&tmcp_date_0** ???

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=11&tmcp_date_0=VALUEOF#epo-build-datepicker" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="11" data-product_sku="" class="add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart epo-build-cart-url-param">Add to cart</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add paramValue with jquery

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/?add-to-cart=11" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="11" data-product_sku="" class="add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart epo-build-cart-url-param">Add to cart</a>

$('a.add_to_cart_button').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var val = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log(val)
})

$( "#epo-build-datepicker" ).datepicker({


    onSelect: function() {
        var dateObject = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        console.log(dateObject);

        var paramValue = $(this).val();
        var _href = $('a.add_to_cart_button').attr('href');
        _href = _href+'&tmcp_date_0'+paramValue;
        $('a.add_to_cart_button').attr('href', _href);


    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//get href value of link
var uri = $(".add_to_cart_button").attr('href');

//assign new param
uri = uri + "&tmcp_date_0="+paramValue;

//assign new uri to a tag
$(".add_to_cart_button").prop("href", uri);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.